# Switch between DLL and .EXE with COM Support in Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, dll, portable-executable

I have the following situation:

I have a delphi application `{$APPTYPE GUI}`. (`APP1`)

If `APP1` gets started, it runs the code between
`begin` and `end.`, just as it should be.

Later, `APP1` will be transformed to a DLL (another application will do that - `APP2`).

`APP2` **adds** the `IMAGE_FILE_DLL` flag to the `Characteristics` in the `NTFileHeader` of `APP1`. 
Then `APP2` tries to load the DLL (`APP1`) with `LoadLibrary` (or some other COM Command to load a dll) but it returns the error:

> Windows encountered an internal error while initializing COM
>   libraries.

I've done all this with a `C` project and used the `WinMain` function. However it seems not to work in Delphi (`APP1` gets not started as a DLL). How is it possible to convert `APP1` to a working DLL?

EDIT:

I'm trying to port this code from `C` to Delphi : http://level-23.info/forum/showthread.php?14721-UAC-Bypass-for-Windows-7-RTM-SP1-Windows-8-DP&p=31749

I've ported it correctly and everything works but the `CRYPTBASE.dll` (`APP1`) doesn't start . (See Error above)

In a nutshell:
Create a delphi application, add the `IMAGE_FILE_DLL` characteristics in the file header. Rename it to `CRYPTBASE.dll` and copy it to C:\Windows\System32\sysprep. Then start `sysprep.exe`

**INFOS HERE:** http://www.pretentiousname.com/misc/W7E_Source/win7_uac_poc_details.html

Comment: I think you'll need to elaborate here. I have absolutely no idea what you mean.

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't export a different function name?  The imported `WinMain` might be conflicting with the host application's `WinMain`...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's about the code from yesterday. Hope you can help me editing the question, so other people understand it as well.

Comment: I don't understand this at all. And I don't really understand what that code was trying to do.

Comment: It seems like that `APP2` calls `LoadLibrary` and `APP1` doesn't start at all, due to the error in the question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I really can't explain it any better, sorry.

Comment: I'm basically looking for a method to use my code as `.exe` as well as `.dll`

Comment: What's the reason for telling us that your application is $Apptype GUI? That's by default any delphi VCL form application and you don't have to declare it anywhere. There's two types, console and gui, which one did you create?

Comment: I've created a console app but I force it with `{$APPTYPE GUI}`.

Comment: I think he wants to have an executable that injects itself into another executable "as a dll"

Comment: No. I want my Application to be executable as well as to be executable if `LoadLibrary` get's called.

Comment: What makes you think the lack of a certain function name causes the message you see, rather than an actual problem initializing COM libraries?

Comment: @RobKennedy Good question, I can't explain it myself, but it works just fine with a `C` Application...

Comment: you must call CoInitialize/CoUninitialize in a console application

Comment: This didn't do the trick.

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss, why do you think that you can enforce {$APPTYPE GUI} onto a console application? It's either a console application or it isn't.

Comment: Exactly. Either I can force it to GUI by manually adding the `{$APPTYPE GUI}` or by changing the project settings.

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss, a VCL form application is by default a GUI application, you don't have to declare it anywhere. If you are creating a console application then the {$AppType CONSOLE} directive is already added automatically when you create a project. You only have to add the console directive if you are creating the unit manually and not through the IDE wizard. Again, you can't force a console application into a GUI one just by declaring the GUI type, it doesn't work like that.

Comment: @PeterVonča It doesn't even matter if the application is a console or GUI type in this question. And yes you can force it! Create a new console project (in XE4) and replace the `{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}` with `{$APPTYPE GUI}`. There you have a proof of concept. BTW. if you create a console project, and you remove the `{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}` it still is a console project, because it's saved in the project settings.

Comment: @PeterVonča Again, you CAN force a console application by replacing the `{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}` to `{$APPTYPE GUI}`. The compiler directive has higher priority than the project settings (which is Console). Proof of conecpt: It will change the `Subsystem` in the Optional Header to `0002` which is `Windows GUI`

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss, I never said that if you remove APPTYPE console that the program is no longer a console project, you misread what I said. And it does matter if you are creating a library.

Comment: @PeterVonča Such compiler directives need to be set in the same unit as where the Entry Point is, you're right. But you said in a comment before that I `[..]can't force a console application into a GUI one just by declaring the GUI type, it doesn't work like that.` This statement is wrong.

Comment: @BenjaminWeiss, regarding the quote, I don't think it came out quite like I wanted it, let me explain, what I wanted to say was that it's pointless to force a GUI APPTYPE on a console application because if you want a GUI application then you just create an actual VCL app. adding that directive in an already created console application gives you nothing, in fact it breaks the application from actually running as a console. That's the whole point that I've been trying to make since first comment. I apologize if I was unclear.

Comment: @PeterVonča Now I understand! My personal reason to force a console app to a GUI is, that I don't need VCL for certain tests or small codes. I usually use Consoles in Debug Mode but in Release I don't need no output. I apologize if I was unclear as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[WinMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a just a name, by convention, to use as the entry point of an executable. The convention for DLL's is to use the name [DllMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The Windows loader does not search for WinMain and LoadLibrary does not search for DllMain, it just calls the entrypoint in the pe header.

Delphi doesn't use either, the exported name of the entry point is start.

WinMain signature differs from DllMain (WinMain takes four parameters), my suggestion is to declare a function DllMain and export it in your exe:

```
function DllMain(hinstDLL: THandle; fdwReason: DWORD; lpvReserverd: Pointer): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  // do something
end;

  exports
    DllMain;
```

The code that modifies your exe (in mem I presume) to be a dll should set the entry point to DllMain (get it's address by walking the EAT).

Also: make sure that the relocation table it not stripped (in release mode) as DLL's require it when they are rebased.

Comment: So, would it be possible to compile a delphi project as a DLL and still use it as an executable when I double click just by changing the `Characteristics` ?

Comment: Most likely not, you'll miss all kinds of initialization (like Delphi RTL)

Comment: I'm sorry I've changed my question, I guess it's like a COM problem or something.

Comment: Awarded you with the bounty. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: No. I gave up on it, but thats ok.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should do that at all. Code is compiled with different assumptions when building EXE and DLLs, it will not work if you simply flip the flag and change the extension.

Trying something like that is a good way to experiment and learn stuff but it's a bad idea for production.

Tell us what are you trying to achieve, in more concrete terms than "To run my DLL as EXE". *Why* do you need to run your DLL as EXE?

For instance, you can build DLL and then load and call it with rundll32. If you need this for COM, you can build an COM host exe and rely on COM's automatic marshalling to achieve the effect of "as if my code was in the same process". It's all already present in COM.

Comment: Look into my question again and read the last `Edit` I've made.

Comment: @Behjamin: Hmm, can't you built two separate modules, one DLL and one EXE, and then use one to load another into Explorer or whatever it's doing?

Comment: I could do that, but I would like to have it in 1 executable file. It doesn't load into explorer. As soon as you start `Sysprep.exe` in `System32\Sysprep` it loads (if exists) `CRYTBASE.DLL`. More infos here: http://www.pretentiousname.com/misc/W7E_Source/win7_uac_poc_details.html

Comment: Just build it as two separate modules and then include the DLL as a resource in the application.  That way, either `APP1.exe` (or `APP2.exe` if you prefer) can extract `CRYPTBASE.DLL` from `APP1.exe` and put it where it is required.